# Grid tuning xgboost with missing data

Tags: r, machine-learning

It seems like the expected method of grid tuning the xgboost model is using the caret package, as clearly displayed here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171043/how-to-tune-hyperparameters-of-xgboost-trees

However, I struggle to make sense of the case with missing data. When creating the model without using caret, I set the missing to NA.

```
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(data = data.matrix(train$data),label = train$label,missing = NA)
```

That allows me to create the model like so:

```
bst = xgboost(data = dtrain,depth = 4,eta =.3,nthread = 2,
          nround = 43, print.every.n = 5,
          objective = "binary:logistic",eval_metric = "auc",verbose = TRUE 
          )
```

This works very nicely, however, caret does not take this kind of object.

This is what I'm trying:

```
xgbtrain = train(x = train$data,y = as.factor(make.names(train$label)), 
             trControl = trControl, tuneGrid = my_grid,method = "xgbTree")
```

But for every iteration it is telling me this:

```
Error in xgb.DMatrix(as.matrix(x), label = y) : can not open file "NA"
```

That's the same error message I was getting before in regular xgb.boost when I didn't set my missing to NA. The xgb.DMatrix is not a subsettable object I could take the data from, and it is also not possible to convert it to a data frame.  How do I get around this?

**EDIT**

Figured it out. In the end, it had nothing to do with missing data, but with having factors in the dataset. Instead of using xgboost's function to convert to a sparse matrix, I used regular model.matrix() and was able to successfully plug in the new matrix into caret's train function.